# Querying multiple properties of List items

Tags: c#, linq, search

I have a List kind of:

```
List<Concept>
  --- Property
  --- List<Class2>
  --- --- Class2pty
  --- --- Class2pty2
  --- List<Class3>
  --- --- Class3pty
```

Having a querystring, I need a new List of **Concepts** that have that querystring on any property (well, a sort of properties), like *Property* or *Class2pty2*, *Class3pty*...

With *Where* I can query *Property* but I don't know how to query *Class2pty* and if it match, return the **Concept** that have that *Class2*

So, Can I do that with a single nested query or what can I do?

**EDIT**: Since I wasn't clear, I give an example

Imagine I have a querystring of "foo" and I have a List with this 4 items

```
Concept
  --- Property = "foo"
  --- List<Class2>
  --- --- Class2pty
  --- --- Class2pty2
  --- List<Class3>
  --- --- Class3pty

Concept
  --- Property
  --- List<Class2>
  --- --- Class2pty = "foo"
  --- --- Class2pty2
  --- List<Class3>
  --- --- Class3pty

Concept
  --- Property
  --- List<Class2>
  --- --- Class2pty = "bar"
  --- --- Class2pty2
  --- List<Class3>
  --- --- Class3pty

Concept
  --- Property
  --- List<Class2>
  --- --- Class2pty
  --- --- Class2pty2
  --- List<Class3>
  --- --- Class3pty = "foo"
```

First list item have **foo** on *Property*, on second item (imagine that List< Class2 > have like 10 instances of *Class2* and one of them (or maybe more)) have **foo** on *Class2Pty*, the third item doesn't have **foo** on any property (in the Concept instance itself and inner instances), four item does have it.

So when any Concept item (incluiding their childs) have a property with that **foo** item, return the Concept item. In our case, 1, 2 and 4.

In short, having a list of concepts with inner lists, return every Concept that have a property with that string or if one of their child instances have it.

Comment: I think after the `.Where()` you could simply do a `.ToList()` and then continue the method chaining.

Comment: I'm not sure. If the Where with Property returns none (no found match) the result list will be empty, so I can't chain.

Comment: This looks like tree traversal with a known depth. So I'm not sure you can do it in a single query.

Comment: Will you know what property you are querying against?  What are the constraints.  If you KNOW what you will be testing you can do...  `list.Where(i => i.Property == "something" && (i.Class2.Where(x => x.Class2pty == "").ToList().Count > 0));`

Comment: It's a known depth List and there is no need for a single query. What you say Jared, is what I tried first, but that doesn't work, you're doing a bool && IEnumerable<Class2>.

Comment: I have a working query string in VS... The difference is that I'm testing that the sub query was populated by generating a List and then checking against the count.  NOT IEnumerable as you mentioned.

Comment: If you don't like the `&&` you can also do... `var newList = list.Where(i => i.MyInt > 0).Where(i => i.MyProperty.Where(x => x == "").ToList().Count > 0)`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my problem. I need the querystring to be just on one property, If the querystring is on Property, stop checking and return the item, if not, check Class2.property, if not, check...

Comment: IF you have a List, you should prefer the List methods `Find()` or `FindAll()` over `Where()`, which is a LINQ method. You can chain `FindAll()` just like you can with `Where()`. The List methods should be slightly faster on large lists, and no need to convert with `ToList()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to select outer classes that match a condition, and contain an inner class that matches conditions?

```
testConcepts.Where( c => c.Property == "SomeValue" 
                         && c.Classes.Any(cls => cls.Class2Pty > 1) );
```

If the Concept does not have a matching property it is eliminated. The Concepts matching the property will be returned if they contain classes that match the expected criteria. (in my example, contain a property with a value > 1, can be any condition.)

To return the child classes that match from containers that match on their property, `.SelectMany()` can be used:

```
testClasses = testConcepts.Where( c => c.Property == "SomeValue")
                       .SelectMany( c => c.Classes ).Where( cls => cls.Class2Pty > 1 );
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first example cover it?
`concepts.Where(c=> c.Property == queryString || c.Class2s.Any(c2=>c2.Class2Pty == queryString) || c.Class3s.Any(c3=>c3.Class3Pty == queryString));`
Obviously with a real class structure this may quickly get ungainly. IMO the primary focus should be on whatever is more readable.

Comment: Yeeeeeep indeed, combination of Where with || but this time using Any (and Exists because I have more annidation) did the trick.